# Ionic Local Notification Sunday

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to schedule weekly notification from datepicker, everything work fine except if user choose Sunday as the day to schedule notification, the Sunday is the 0 day and I get that schedule at null

```
let today = new Date(this.data.date);
          let hour = today.getUTCHours();
          let minutes = today.getMinutes();
          this.weekly = today.getDay();

          this.id = res.insertId;
          db.executeSql("UPDATE payments SET reminder = ? WHERE rowid = ?",[this.id,this.rowid])

          this.localNotifications.schedule({
            id: this.id,
            text: 'Weekly Reminder for '+ this.data.description+ ' '+ 'Amount: €' + this.data.amount,
            every: {  count: 1,  weekday: this.weekly, hour: hour, minute: minutes, second: 1  },
            data: {"id":  this.id, "name": "Mr.A"},
            foreground: true,  


         });
```

Comment: Please provide more information! What is in `this.data.date` and where is the script failing, does it even fail? And why are you using UTC just in hours? If the problem is that if this.weekly is equal to 0 (what means false) and you check in (I think you build the schedule by yourself?) if weekday is set, you should better check if it is a number between 0-6.

Comment: the this.data.date is the date that I get from datepicker, its working for all days except sunday,as I understand the script cannot understand the week day 0, for the rest 1-6 is working fine

Comment: Where is localNotification coming from? If its a package from ionic (never used notifications) then fill in an issue on its issue oage maybe?